# OpenCV opening file error (Assertion failed)

Tags: python, opencv

Working on this code, OpenCV gives me error:

*OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow, file C:\bld\opencv_1498174012660\work\opencv-3.2.0\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 304*

*Traceback (most recent call last):*

*File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Flow/FlowP/detect-extration - temp.py", line 34, in*

*cv2.imshow('win',img)*

*cv2.error: C:\bld\opencv_1498174012660\work\opencv-3.2.0\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:304: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow*

```
now = datetime.now()
id_folder = now.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S-%f')

b_temp = ('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\b_temp\\' + id_folder)
os.makedirs(b_temp, exist_ok=True)


src = ('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Images\\')
files = os.listdir(src)
print(files)


shutil.move(str(src + str(files[0])),b_temp)


img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\b_temp\\' + id_folder + '.tif')
print(img)
cv2.imshow('win', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

What it could be ? All modules are imported right, the code seems to work until the first OpenCV instruction...

Edit: from what I saw, it doesn't recognize the file in the directory...but the file exist, is there...

Here is what it looks:

[image: tree exapmle]

Comment: `img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Images\\' + '.tif')` Is this doing what it's supposed to be doing? You're not adding a filename.

Comment: Updated the code... The folder from where the file need to be open is a folder which is created just before (a unique folder, see id_folder). OpenCV need to read the .tif file from it..

Comment: The code in your post still looks wrong, but I'll assume your actual code looks correct. Bummer, that would have been a nice, easy fix.

Comment: The error is with cv2.imshow() especially..

Comment: And the image that you're trying to open definitely isn't an empty image?

Comment: If I try to print(img) it gives me 'None'... wtf....The image is there, in the folder I want it to be..

Comment: @BlueTrack please check image exist on "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\b_temp\\' "  on that path ,as you per your error it comes when you call imshow with image= None

Comment: Image doesn't exist in b_temp (and it don't have to be in there but in a subfolder created before) b_temp creates folder and another one inside it, id_folder. Images need to be in this last one, and, in fact they are. But imshow() don't recognize them... How is possible ? I think the path is right..

Comment: @Kallz if I give the full path to the file (so with subfolder name and filename.tif) to cv2.imread(), it works...

Comment: Is like the file is not seeing by imread and imshow...But it is there, I tested it.. Could be an error in the folder tree ??

Comment: from what i see in your code and image, you are missing the filename. So, you have `'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\b_temp\\' + id_folder + '.tif'` but id_folder is something like 20170723-014211-466528.... but after id_folder you need to put also another \\ and the file name like 16, not only the extension. (unless your code is different from the one here)

Comment: All the images are different, this is the reason I used *. Filenames are different for every image..

Comment: The reason of error could be this: imread can't see the file because of the path. I mean, setting the whole path of the file, it works. But I need to do the job with variable path. id_folder is variable and so the name of the imag file. Something is wrong with this process...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. This is the right answer...

```
img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\b_temp\\' + id_folder + '\\' + str(files[0]))
```